# partial match , append and explode

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Table 1**

```
|Location|Type|Supplier|     ID    |Serial|
|   MAB  |Ant |  A     |    A123   |456/56|
|   MEB  |Ant |  B     |    A123   |456/56|
```

**Table 2**

```
|Location   |Type|Supplier|     ID      |Serial|#####|
|  MAB+MEB  |Ant |  A/B   | A123        |456/56|123-4|
|  MAB+MEB  |Ant |  A/B   | A123/B123   |456/56|432-1|
|  MAB+MEB  |Ant |  A/B   | A123/B123   |456/56|432-1|
```

**Table 3**

```
|Location|Type|Supplier|     ID    |Serial|#####|
|   MAB  |Ant |  A     | A123      |456/56|123-4|
|   MAB  |Ant |  A     | A123      |456/56|432-1|
|   MAB  |Ant |  A     | A123      |456/56|432-1|
|   MEB  |Ant |  B     | A123      |456/56|123-4|
|   MEB  |Ant |  B     | A123      |456/56|432-1|
|   MEB  |Ant |  B     | A123      |456/56|432-1|
```

As illustrated above , if Table 1 column 'Location' , 'Supplier' , 'ID' , 'Serial' cell content is contained in the same column cells of Table 2 , to generate Table 3.

*Note that Table 1 is used as the core template, if there the relevant column cells are contained in Table 2 , we are merely replicating the rows in Table 1 and adding the '####' column to each of the rows.

Please advice how do we produce Table 3.

My logic: for a,b,c,d in table 1 , if a,b,c,d contained in table 2 , append 'Subcon Part #' from table 2 to table 1 by column, Concate all 'Subcon Part #' by ',' explode concated 'Subcon Part #' to generate rows with unique 'Subcon Part #'

Where a,b,c,d are the columns of interests , the links between Table 1 and 2